Are integrals just approximations of area?
When we try to solve some problems with integration, we face some problems and a bit of confusion.
Now, if we want to determine the area of an object, we have some specific formula to determine the area of the object. But if we go to determine the area of a complex object, which has no specific pattern and formula to determine the area of a complex object, we use integration to solve the problems of those complex objects.
Basically, we divide the complex object into $n$ number of parts and the width of each part is $\mathrm{d}x$ (tiny to see). The width is above and closer to the curve of the complex object. If we divide the objects into an infinite number of parts, those parts would become closer to the object (too close to the object).
But the curve is high in many places and low in many places, how do we consider a constant value for height, which is $f(x)$? No matter how many parts we divide the complex object into, the shape of the curve would remain the same. It means the divided parts of the complex object would not be the same as we divide it into an infinite number of parts.

You may be mixing up Riemann sums and Riemann integrals, which are limits of Riemann sums.

We assume that for an infinitesimal change in x: $\Delta x\rightarrow dx$ the value of function $f(x)$ remains constant.

Imagine a line to be a rectangle of $dx$ thickness. Draw a line $x=a$. Is the value of $f(x)$ constant where the line meets the curve or does it give 2 different values?
